# What does this use of little-o notation mean?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I am currently going through the proof of Prime Number Theorem, as given in Hardy and Wright, and in it they define the following constant:

$$\alpha = \limsup_\limits{x \to \infty} \left|V(x) \right|$$

It then states:
$$|V(x)| \leq \alpha + o(1)$$

The book explains that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ means that $f(x)/g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and likewise $f(x)=o(1)$ simply means that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. It also states that the use of $o(g(x))$ in an equation simply means "some unspecified function f(x) such that f(x)=o(g(x))". This definition makes sense to me when the equation is an equality, however I don't know how to interpret this statement, which is an inequality.

Does it mean that there is a specific function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=o(1)$ and $|V(x)| \leq \alpha + f(x)$?

Does it mean that for all functions $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=o(1)$, the inequality $|V(x)| \leq \alpha + f(x)$ remains true (at least for sufficiently large $x$)?

Comment: Aren't the two statements you mentioned equivalent for sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: That may be true, but I'm not even sure if either is correct, and I don't quite see how the definition of alpha implies it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of the big-oh and little-oh notation is to provide a way to write down that a particular function is negligible/is of the same order as another simpler function in a rigorous way. It allows us to deal with possibly disgusting and unpredictable functions by comparing them to much simpler functions of the same order.

The point is that once we've written $f(x)=o(g(x))$, we no longer care what $f(x)$ actually is; just that it is in a sense "smaller than $g(x)$".

With this in mind, whilst the way to read it would probably be $$|V(x)|\le \alpha +\text{a function that is equal to }o(1),$$
the take home message is 
$$|V(x)|\le \alpha +\text{something which tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$,}$$
or perhaps in this context
$$|V(x)|\le \alpha +\text{an error term that is negligible for large $x$.}$$

---

EDIT as per the comments.

If any function $f(x)\to \alpha$ as $ x\to \infty$, then by definition, $f(x)-\alpha=o(1)$, so $$f(x)= \alpha +o(1).$$

In the case of $\limsup$, we have$$\alpha =\limsup_{x\to\infty}f(x) =\lim_{x\to\infty}\big(\sup_{y\ge x}f(y)\big),$$
So for any $x$ we have $$f(x)\le\sup_{y\ge x}f(y)=\alpha + o(1).$$

Comment: My question is more "why $|V(x)| \leq \alpha + o(1)$ instead of $|V(x)| = \alpha + o(1)$. Surely if $|V(x)|-\alpha \leq $ a function which tends to 0, then $|V(x)|-\alpha$ also tends to zero, hence the equality follows. Likewise, if it tends to zero, then it is certainly less than some function which tends to zero (twice itself).

Comment: An example would be $\sin x +\frac 1 x \le 1+o(1)$, which works as an inequality and is a good bound, but would not be an equality. However there is no better upper bound for this function.

Comment: The point is that we're trying to create an upper bound of the form "main term" + "controlled error term". But it is still an upper bound, so is an inequality.

Comment: So is the inequality given inherent from the definition of alpha?

Comment: In this case yes. For example if $V(x) =\alpha\sin x +\frac 1x$, then there would need to be an inequality. We can only get an inequality from the definition of $\limsup$ (just as the regular supremum only gives you an upper bound). The error term comes from the fact that the $\limsup$ is a limit.

Comment: Your example is very helpful, and I do understand how that case works, however I am having trouble seeing how the general case works. Can you give me some assistance as to how I can see how alpha being defined as the lim sup of a function implies the given inequality. In the case you have given, the $o(1)$ is explicitly $1/x$, however I am having trouble seeing what the $o(1)$ function is in the general case.

Comment: Or in other words, you have given me a function in which it is easy to deduce that the lim sup is $\alpha$ and the inequality also holds. I am having trouble starting with just the fact that the lim sup is $\alpha$ and deducing from there that there is a function equal to $o(1)$ such that the inequality holds

Comment: I've edited the post to explain this in general. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the detail I was missing.